# Would "Bane: Human" affect Kalashtar?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, eberron

Would human-bane weapons do extra damage against the `Kalashtar`?

`Kalashtar` look similar to humans (to the point they get a disguise bonus), originated as `humans`, and the main differences are mental/psionic, so it makes sense that they would, but are there rules to back that up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes.

Kalashtar are [humanoids of the human subtype](http://eberron.wikia.com/wiki/Kalashtar). As a result, [human-bane weapons](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm) are effective on them.

Answer (score 1):

`Kalashtar` have human bodies, but they have two spirits inside it: one `Human-spirit` and one `Quori-spirit`. I think that a `Bane (humans)` magic weapon *"recognizes"* the body which it hits and not the spirit insideit because if we were talking about enthralled or psionically manipulated humans there wouldn't be no problem, would it?